# How do you translate strings to padded binary in python?

Tags: python

I have made a program that translates a text into binary code but its really messy. This is my code:

```
def converter():
    print("message:")
    inputMsg = input()
    msg = ''
    for letter in inputMsg:
        if letter == 'a':
            msg = msg + '01100001'
        elif letter == 'b':
            msg = msg + '01100010'
        elif letter == 'c':
            msg = msg + '01100011'
        elif letter == 'd':
            msg = msg + '01100100'
        elif letter == 'e':
            msg = msg + '01100101'
        elif letter == 'f':
            msg = msg + '01100110'
        elif letter == 'g':
            msg = msg + '011000111'
        elif letter == 'h':
            msg = msg + '01101000'
        elif letter == 'i':
            msg = msg + '01101001'
        elif letter == 'j':
            msg = msg + '01101010'
        elif letter == 'k':
            msg = msg + '01101011'
        elif letter == 'l':
            msg = msg + '01101100'
        elif letter == 'm':
            msg = msg + '01101101'
        elif letter == 'n':
            msg = msg + '01101110'
        elif letter == 'o':
            msg = msg + '01101111'
        elif letter == 'p':
            msg = msg + '01110000'
        elif letter == 'q':
            msg = msg + '01110001'
        elif letter == 'r':
            msg = msg + '01100010'
        elif letter == 's':
            msg = msg + '01110011'
        elif letter == 't':
            msg = msg + '01110100'
        elif letter == 'u':
            msg = msg + '01110101'
        elif letter == 'v':
            msg = msg + '01110110'
        elif letter == 'w':
            msg = msg + '01110111'
        elif letter == 'x':
            msg = msg + '01111000'
        elif letter == 'y':
            msg = msg + '01111001'
        elif letter == 'z':
            msg = msg + '01111010'

        elif letter == 'A':
            msg = msg + '01000001'
        elif letter == 'B':
            msg = msg + '01000010'
        elif letter == 'C':
            msg = msg + '01000011'
        elif letter == 'D':
            msg = msg + '01000100'
        elif letter == 'E':
            msg = msg + '01000101'
        elif letter == 'F':
            msg = msg + '01000110'
        elif letter == 'G':
            msg = msg + '01000111'
        elif letter == 'H':
            msg = msg + '01001000'
        elif letter == 'I':
            msg = msg + '01001001'
        elif letter == 'J':
            msg = msg + '01001010'
        elif letter == 'K':
            msg = msg + '01001011'
        elif letter == 'L':
            msg = msg + '01001100'
        elif letter == 'M':
            msg = msg + '01001101'
        elif letter == 'N':
            msg = msg + '01001110'
        elif letter == 'O':
            msg = msg + '01001111'
        elif letter == 'P':
            msg = msg + '01010000'
        elif letter == 'Q':
            msg = msg + '01010001'
        elif letter == 'R':
            msg = msg + '01000010'
        elif letter == 'S':
            msg = msg + '01010011'
        elif letter == 'T':
            msg = msg + '01010100'
        elif letter == 'U':
            msg = msg + '01010101'
        elif letter == 'V':
            msg = msg + '01010110'
        elif letter == 'W':
            msg = msg + '01010111'
        elif letter == 'X':
            msg = msg + '01011000'
        elif letter == 'Y':
            msg = msg + '01011001'
        elif letter == 'Z':
            msg = msg + '01011010'
        elif letter == ' ':
            msg = msg + '00100000'

    print('\n',msg,'\n')
    print('do again?  (y/n)')
    yn()

def yn():
    yn = input()
    if yn == 'y':
        converter()
    elif yn == 'n':
        pass
    else:
        yn()


 converter()
```

My output is OK but you see i have an if/else for every letter. Is there an other way to do it clean and a bit more efficient?

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, you could consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com. In general, a dictionary is a good replacement for lots of `elif`s.

Comment: @svs I updated my answer, I had missed out on the positive/negative number identifier, so was only 7 bits long! Fixed now

Comment: Can we update Question header, to read. "How do you translate strings to padded binary?" please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> st = "hello"
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), '08b') for x in st)
'01101000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
```

What happens here is that we loop over every character, `x`, in string `st`. On each of those items we run [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), which converts the character `x` into a integer representing the Unicode code point, e.g. `'T' == 84`. This number we then [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) into (padded) binary. `08` here means that the number is to be formatted to be 8 digits long, padded by `0` from the left. `b` then indicates that it is to be in binary, or base 2. The number has to be padded or there would be no leading zeroes.

Comment: This answer could really use some explanation! Remember that some beginners might stumble upon this answer few years from now. I find it a good habit to even further improve all my questions once they get approved, since you usually rely on the accepted answer when looking for information.

Comment: I've added an explanation. Thing it's good, or anything I should expand on?